# get the values from all form elements in onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, in which I have 15 comboboxes, and one check box. I am trying to get all current values in the form in onchange event.

My code so far:

```
function update_number_of_adds_found(field_dropdown, selected_value) {
    for (i = 0; i < document.submitadd.elements.length; i++) {
        alert("The field name is: " + document.submitadd.elements[i].name +
            " and it’s value is: " + document.submitadd.elements[i].value);
    }
    // var result5 = $.ajax({
    //   'url': '<?php echo site_url('search/findNumberOfAdds'); ?>/' + selected_value,
    //   'async': false
    // }).responseText;
    // $('#totalNumOfAdds').empty();
    // $("#totalNumOfAdds").append(result5);
}
```

Code above works so far, that is in the alert i get the values. Now, i would like to place those variables in the variables and send those variables in the ajax request bellow.

Anyone can help me with this?
Regards, John

Comment: why not just use [`$(formSelector).serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)?

Comment: Could this be what you're looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018120/send-an-array-of-values-through-a-ajax-post

Comment: The only reason is that I don't know how. Not a javascript / jquery master actually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned jQuery so I assume it's acceptable to you:

`$('form').serialize()` creates a string for ajax-style data submissions

If you need all the elements, just use `$('form').find('input,select,textarea')` etc

Comment: That work, but now i am getting message that my ulr contain dissalowed characters...i guess that problem arrise with the &. How can i replace that character? Aslo, do you know how to get only the values where the value is not null?

Comment: `serialize` is meant for GET/POST requests and will function properly. It builds a format like '&fieldName=fieldValue` which is correct. You can easily build your own array/string of field names/values using the jquery selector I gave above. Just check for the field `.val()` being empty